# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS super key - searching - increase the number of files displayed

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, search, activities-overview

What is the way to increase the number of files displayed if searching in making usage of the <kbd>super</kbd> key?

How to reproduce?

1. press the <kbd>super</kbd> key
2. type a search string

   'Files' icon is displayed on the left.
   On the right, a list of files or directories.
   If I count correctly '5' items are displayed.

**What is the way to increase the '5' items displayed?**

Comment: This is probably hard coded, so one would need to edit source code somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Workaround***

it is possible to increase the number globally..
Meaning for all the search results. Not individually for Files app.

You may create a Gnome-Shell Extension on your own with below content in the `extension.js` file.

```
function init() {}

function enable() { imports.ui.search.MAX_LIST_SEARCH_RESULTS_ROWS=10; }

function disable() { imports.ui.search.MAX_LIST_SEARCH_RESULTS_ROWS=5; }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am impressed by the effort you made to solve this question! I will review the proposed solution asap. Thanks.

Comment: I have run gssr.sh (local). ALT+F2 r.
Sorry Still 5 items displayed. :-( 
Gnome is 3.28.2. 
In the code I have found   "3.28". Is 3.28.2 supported?

Comment: Hi.. Sorry can you run `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` and enable the extension please..

Comment: OK. Thanks. Would you be kind to update the readme on Github.
I have lots of experience on 16.04 LTS (Unity) and it is why I didn't know it was necessary to activate the plugin.

Comment: General comment. It should possible to configure the MAX_LIST_SEARCH_RESULTS_ROWS without the installation of a workaround (plugin).