# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS super key - searching - file manager 'no result found' (bug?/misconfiguration?)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, search, activities-overview

Searching in making usage of the <kbd>super</kbd> key gives the possibility to use the 'file manager' (Nautilus) to access the files.

The problem is that if the 'file manager' is clicked, even if 'x' files was displayed/retrieved, the 'file manager' displays 'no result found' (bug?/misconfiguration?).

How to reproduce:

1. press the <kbd>super</kbd> key
2. type a search string

'Files' icon is displayed on the left and a counter, for example '69 more'. On the right, a list of files or directories.

Clicking on the 'Files' icons does return **'no result found'**. This is incorrect! (in my example of course).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS super key - searching - increase the number of files displayed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203105/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-super-key-searching-increase-the-number-of-files-displaye)

Comment: @nobody:Funny, you make reference to a question without any answer I have asked this morning. ;-)

Comment: Probably a bug in 18.04, which actually uses a version of file manager that is older than the version that comes with the corresponding shell. Works correctly in 19.10, i.e., clicking "File manager" correctly opens nautilus with the corresponding search initiated.